# gcc not found while executing shell script

Tags: bash, gcc, environment-variables, ns2

invalid command name "gcc"
    while executing
"gcc rsa.c -o rsa -lm"
    (file "./run.sh" line 1)

does gcc-4.9.2 works correctly on ns-2.35 or is it gcc-4.4

Comment: What's the CLI output of `which gcc`?

Comment: gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) this is the version of gcc i'm using..

Comment: Any way we can take a look at the contents of `run.sh`?

Comment: gcc rsa.c -o rsa -lm
./rsa
ns main.tcl

Comment: I'm glad to know your version of gcc, but what's the output of `which gcc`.  What happens when you place `which gcc` at the top of your script and try to run it.  It should have output.

Comment: invalid command name "gcc" while executing "gcc rsa.c -o rsa -lm" (file "./run.sh" line 1)   this is the output of gcc-4.8.4 which i'm using now

Comment: gcc-4: /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 /usr/bin/X11/gcc-4.8 /usr/bin/X11/gcc-4.6 /usr/bin/X11/gcc-4.9 /usr/bin/X11/gcc-4.4    these are the versions of gcc in my system and i'm running gcc-4.8

Comment: invalid command name "gcc" while executing "gcc rsa.c -o rsa -lm" (file "./run.sh" line 1)   my question is i have installed gcc but why am i getting this error as invalid command...??

Comment: Yeah, but I'm asking you to change your file to look like this: http://pastie.org/private/gustqjww03d5tplyigznmw .  I want to see the actual output of these commands, not your interpretation of my question.

Comment: invalid command name "which"
    while executing
"which gcc"
    (file "./run.sh" line 1)

Comment: So, it looks like your Environmental Variables are messed up.  You're missing things, such as `$PATH`, most likely.  Maybe it's as simple as placing `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script, but it seems like you have bigger problems than that.  What shell is it using?  `echo $0` should tell you if it's `sh` or `bash` or what.

Comment: yes u r right ... pls help  me to set a proper path may be i wish to put gcc-4.4 as default

Comment: Have you tried opening a new terminal?  That one might have gotten messed up in some way.  Can the terminal you're in run *any* commands?  What happens if you run `which gcc` in the terminal, not in the script?  Does it actually give you good output?

Comment: Your issue is *NOT* gcc right now.  If `which` won't work, most likely nothing will work.  We need to get your shell working by determining which shell you're using and why your Environmental Variables aren't loading.

Comment: /usr/bin/gcc   this is what i am getting on running the command "which gcc"

Comment: Okay, so the issue here is that whatever is running your script is not loading up your environmental variables.  I'm not really sure the solution.  What happens when you add `#!/bin/bash` to the top of the script?  Does that help at all?

Comment: no i'm gettintg the same thing when i add the above thing..

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/4eo8td8hv6hedgv1f4wwq

Comment: Is it `bash run.sh` vs `./run.sh` that's making it work?

Comment: i really appreciate ur time and dedication ..#earthmeLon thanks again ..

Comment: #!/bin/bash
echo $0
echo $PATH
which gcc
gcc rsa.c -o rsa -lm
./rsa
ns main.tcl

i mean               bash run.sh

Comment: "*invalid command name*" sounds more like a `tcl` error than a bash one: are you **sure** you are executing this command in a bash shell?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the script as `./run.sh`,  be sure that the first line of the script is `#!/bin/bash` and run it with `bash run.sh`.